# CSV files is showing absurd character instead of chinese or korean

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created a generic method which downloads a csv file for any input. I am facing issue with the chinese and korean character as they are coming differently in the csv file.[image]

```
private IActionResult ReturnCsvFile<T>(IEnumerable<T> users)
        {
            var csvString = new StringBuilder();
            Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);

            var propInfos = typeParameterType.GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).OrderBy(x => x.MetadataToken)
                .Select(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>());

            csvString.AppendLine(string.Join(",", propInfos.Select(x => x.PropertyName)));
            var counter = 1;
            foreach (var item in users)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] props = item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).OrderBy(x => x.MetadataToken).ToArray();
                props[0].SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(counter++, props[0].PropertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), null);
                string commaSeperatedValues = string.Join(",", props.Select(prop => "\"" + Convert.ToString(prop.GetValue(item), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "\""));
                csvString.AppendLine(commaSeperatedValues);
            }
            var test = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(csvString.ToString());
            return File(test, "text/csv", "UsersList.csv");
        }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check if `users` display the characters correct. Probably the encoding is wrong when you assign the `users` property in other code.

Comment: Characters are coming correctly in users. I checked all the encoding like utf7,utf8, utf16, latin1, unicode but no luck.

Comment: What tool are you using to view the downloaded file? Try simply opening it with Notepad. Does that look rigth?

Comment: Since you want to transmit in essence a string, can you use the `Content(string content, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding)` method instead of doing the decoding the string into a byte array and File(...) it? If that alone does not fix your issue or you don't want that, try using the UTF-8 encoding with BOM, i.e. `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: @PoulBak If I am opening the file in a notepad++ then the characters are coming properly. If the file gets opened in Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv) or excel then Chinese characters are not coming properly.

Comment: https://www.scrapehero.com/unicode/#:~:text=How%20To%20Open%20a%20Unicode%20CSV%20in%20Excel,then%20click%20Open%20%28or%20Import%20%29.%20Flere%20elementer

Comment: https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-display-csv-files-with-unicode-utf-8-encoding-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

**Excel can't open Unicode files without a BOM (Byte Order Mark).**

It will open them as Ansi files, which will show unicode characters as garbage.

Since you're using `Encoding.GetBytes()` there will **never** be a BOM.

To get a BOM, you must use `StreamWriter`.

You can fix that by replacing the last 2 lines by this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new())
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new(ms, new UTF8Encoding(true)))
    {
        sw.Write(csvString);
    }
}
return File(ms, "text/csv", "UsersList.csv");
```

Now there should be a BOM and Excel should be able to to open it correctly.